# Creating a quarterly time interview using ggplot and lubridate

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, lubridate, timeserieschart

I've created a time series plot using ggplot and lubridate that depicts disease incidents over a two year period. I can't seem to find a way of getting the X axis labels to depict years and quarters.

```
library(tidyverse)
Event.number <- c(1:30)
Event.date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2012/12/31'), by="day"), 30)      
Disease <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B","A", "A", "B", "A", "B","A", "A", "B", "A", "B","A", "A", "B", "A", "B" ,"A", "A", "B", "A", "B","A", "A", "B", "A", "B")

data.frame(Event.number, Event.date, Disease) %>% 
  mutate(Year.Quarter = quarter(Event.date, with_year = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(Event.number, Year.Quarter, Disease) %>% 
  group_by(Year.Quarter, Disease) %>% 
  count(name = "Cases") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Year.Quarter, Cases, colour = Disease))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps take a look at `scale_x_yearqtr` with `zoo` package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment under the question, change the  `mutate` as shown to use `yearqtr` class and add `scale_x_yearqtr()` to the `ggplot` command.  Also note that the `group_by`/`count` statements can be reduced to just a `count` statement. See the `format=` argument at `?scale_x_yearqtr` for further customization of the label.

```
library(zoo)

DF <-  data.frame(Event.number, Event.date, Disease) %>% 
  mutate(Year.Quarter = as.yearqtr(Event.date)) %>%
  select(Event.number, Year.Quarter, Disease) %>% 
  count(Year.Quarter, Disease, name = "Cases")

ggplot(DF, aes(Year.Quarter, Cases, colour = Disease)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_x_yearqtr(n = 99)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck that works perfectly. Can I ask - is it possible to have the x axis labels include the years (only at the actual year intervals) and the quarters in-between  (using major and minor lines?) I realise that this is a slight different question and am perfectly happy with the solution that you provide above.

Comment: One more short request for advice: should I be learning to use the zoo package instead of lubridate? (is that consider to be the newer, more up-to-date way of dealing with time/date data?)

Comment: Actually zoo pre-dates lubridate. It is mainly for time series but does define yearmon and yearqtr classes which seem useful even beyond that.